# About the [macbook] tag and synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't have a portable and so never was interested in all the MacBook related tags.

However a question came up in the suggested edit queue where [macbook-pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macbook-pro) was definitely the wrong tag as [macbook-air](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macbook-air) would be better.

However I then discovered that they were all synonymized to the same tag. Which is a reasonable solution.

What is not reasonable is that this tag is [macbook-pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macbook-pro); surely [macbook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macbook) should be the tag that is shown and selectable as people who have an air  definitely don't have a pro and so would not search for it or look at questions tagged [macbook-pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macbook-pro).

Comment: Not sure it really matters, searching for tag `macbook` automatically results in a search for `macbook-pro`.

Comment: Which I then spent 5-10 minutes debugging as macbook-pro was wrong. and macbook-air and macbook did not appear

Comment: Maybe I miss something important here, but it doesn't matter whether one uses `macbook`, `macbook-pro` or `macbook-air` during a search, it will always return the same set of questions. Where did `macbook-air` not appear?

Comment: The question was https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/413711/battery-indicator-on-macbook-air which is definitely about an air and not pro - when tagging I had no idea they were the same - I use tags more for visual info not searching. If I had a macbook-air I would not look at questions tagged macbook-pro as that is a different machine

Comment: Ah, got it, the system doesn't auto-propose tag synonyms while editing. Yeah, that's rather confusing in this case.

Comment: I just wanted to “complain” that someone had added the `macbook-pro` tag to a question about an MacBook Air, but then noticed that they are synonyms. `macbook` would definitely be the better (and less confusing) tag that all other `macbook-*` tags are redirected to.